# What will happen if a single AWS region center becomes unavailable?

Tags: amazon-web-services

What will happen if an individual AWS region becomes unavailable? I am quoting from their website that says that,

> It is important to remember that each AWS Region is completely
>   independent. Any Amazon RDS activity you initiate (for example,
>   creating database instances or listing available database instances)
>   runs only in your current default AWS Region. The default AWS Region
>   can be changed in the console, by setting the EC2_REGION environment
>   variable, or it can be overridden by using the --region parameter with
>   the AWS Command Line Interface.

It is my wish to have at least several synchronized data centers in the event of downtime.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this is a genuine question and concern of mine, and I am surprised I got down voted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite clear: Your data is not replicated to other AWS regions. If you need to have replication between multiple regions you need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle an entire region failure. Handling an availability zone failure is not covered in my answer but is very easy with AWS today. Most good architectures automatically handle AZ failure.

**A good answer on AWS disaster recovery would fill an entire book.**

You have to balance time to recover with how much it will cost to continously backup and replicate everything.

1. Create backups / snapshots of your data and copy to a different region. There are different types of snapshots / backups / AMIs for different AWS services. In the event of a region failure you can manually recover from the backups. For the most part this is a manual human involved process. You can combine DevOps here to automate the recreation of your services and resources, e.g. CloudFormation.
2. Implement designs that uses services that use multiple regions. For example, you could use CloudFront, Load Balancers, Route53, Geolocation and Health Checks to create a multi-region web site. The failure of a region would be detected and traffic can be rerouted to another region. This could have a very fast recovery time (the time for the health check to fail).
3. One issue today with AWS is multi region multi master databases. Amazon Aurora is currently heading towards this goal, but today you will need to purchase third party databases designed for this purpose.

Most standard disaster recovery architectures and continuity plans apply to AWS. AWS has some things that make everything easier, but for the most part the Cloud is just a collection of data centers. The same thought processes apply.

Do a Google search on AWS Disaster Recovery. There are lots of good resources available.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb happens to have in their API, availability for replica set support as such:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:30000,localhost:30001,localhost:30002/integration_test_?w=1", function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  assert.ok(db != null);

  db.collection("replicaset_mongo_client_collection").update({a:1}, {b:1},{upsert:true}, function(err, result) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  assert.equal(1, result);

db.close();
});
```